# How to fix triggers after adding network start position to game objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Hello I am new to using unity and C#. I'm currently making a game for a project where I used a pacman tutorial and making it multiplayer. I've managed to get the multiplayer part working however, once I added two game objects that have Network Start Position and added to a network manager under spawn info, my triggers stopped working all of a sudden. My player object should make the Pacman Dots disappear when it collides with it and My player object should disappear when it collides with a pacman ghost. Could anyone tell me whats going on?

My PlayerObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class UFOMove : NetworkBehaviour 
{
    public float speed;             

    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;      

    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");       
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");      
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, moveVertical);       
        rb2d.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }
}
```

My Ghost Movement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GhostMove : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform[] waypoints;
    int cur = 0;

    public float speed = 0.3f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (transform.position != waypoints[cur].position)
        {
            Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                                            waypoints[cur].position,
                                            speed);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(p);
        }
        else 
            cur = (cur + 1) % waypoints.Length;

        Vector2 dir = waypoints[cur].position - transform.position;
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirX", dir.x);
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirY", dir.y);

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co)
    {
        if (co.name == "UFO")
            Destroy(co.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Pacman Dot:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PacDot : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co)
    {
        if (co.name == "UFO")
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you man by `stopped working`? Are you getting any errors? Are the trigger codes in general not called or do you get unexpected behaviours?

Comment: I have no errors at all. Before I implemented Spawn on different locations when using the client, my triggers worked perfectly. The dots would disappear and the player object would disappear. Once I implemented the spawn on different locations, the triggers don't do what they're supposed to do. My player object just hovers over them instead of colliding. @derHugo

Answer (score 1):

I have just realized the problem. Answering my own question just in case some other people have trouble. Adding the multiplayer function on the game changes the name of the PlayerObject. For me my  UFO would change its name to UFO(Clone) every time it's run on Local Host and Client. So instead of looking for the name of the object onTriggerEnter, I changed the code so that it looks for a tag. I added a tag to my playerObject so that it could be found.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co)
{
    if (co.tag == "UFO")
        Destroy(co.gameObject);
}
```